# google apps script Spreadsheet and Bigquery querying

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

Following the example from

https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/blob/master/advanced/bigquery.gs#L26-L28

I was trying to run a query in bigquery, but I am getting
"Invalid table name: `my_db:my_dataset.my_table` [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]. (line 68, file "bigquery")

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run following query:

```
SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count ' +
      'FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;'
```

in BigQuery console, which is provided in Legacy Dialect,  ensure that you have enabled option:  Use Legacy SQL in [Options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)

Or you could [migrate query from LEGACY to STANDARD SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql):

```
 SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count 
    FROM `publicdata.samples.shakespeare` WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;
```

Additionally if you want to run STANDARD SQL queries from Google App Script add flag useLegacySql as below:

```
var job = {
configuration: {
  query: {
    query: 'SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count +
        FROM `publicdata.samples.shakespeare` WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;',
    useLegacySql: false
    }
```